# AspectJ compiler DeclareMixin error

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I'm using the `@DeclareMixin` provided by `aspectjrt-1.6.11`.

The situation is:

```
    @Aspect
    public class anAspect {

      @DeclareMixin(value="@an.annotation.package.* *", interfaces = {
        FirstInterface.class, SecondInterface.class, ThirdInterface.class
      })
      public AggregateInterface magicMethod(Object instance) {
        return new AggregateInterfaceImpl(instance);
      }

      public interface AggregateInterface extends FirstInterface, 
        SecondInterface, ThirdInterface {
      }
}
```

So when i compile via `aspectj-maven-plugin-1.4`, the compiler says that the factory method (magicMethod() in my case) does not return something that implements any of the interfaces implemented.

The problem came out when I've introduced the Second and Third interface in the `AggregateInterfaceImpl`.

Have you got any idea of the problem? Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue declaring different mixins attached to different factory methods.